# Leaflet.draw mapping: How to initiate the draw function without toolbar FROM R?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, polygon, draw

I am using *leaflet* and *leaflet.extras* to draw information on a map in an *R/Shiny* application. I need to draw a polygon to permit the user select the map features within a desired area, but I would prefer not to have the Draw toolbar but directly invoke the draw.polygon function.

I have found that can be done in javascript with

`new L.Draw.Polygon(map, drawControl.options.polygon).enable()`

but I don't know how to do it directly from an R script. Is it even possible?

Any help would be appreciated...